# How to print all but the last 20 lines of each file in the /tmp dir.?

Tags: linux, shell, command, redhat

Print all but the last 20 lines of each file in the /tmp dir.

linux redhat 4-5

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
head -n -20 filename
```

Comment: Not the downvoter. I would guess 2 things: this is actually a comment because you say "Try this" instead of saying that your command actually answers the question. Second, you did not explain the command or why it solves the problem. $0.02

Comment: i wrote this answer when i was new to SO. At that point of time, i was not allowed to comment, only answers are possible. That's why . hope this helps